# Firebird : last sunday of a month

Tags: firebird

How will you find last Sunday of a month in Firebird?

```sql
select extract(week from encodedate(31,12,2009)) from rdb$database
```

Comment: Do you always know the final date of the month (e.g., 2009-12-31) or just the month itself (e.g., 2009-12)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```sql
select dateadd(-1 * extract(weekday from date '31.12.2009') day to date '31.12.2009')
from rdb$database
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.
@pilcrow : Yes I Know the final date of the month, actually I wanted the number of Sundays in a specific year so this should work:

    select extract(week from (select dateadd(-1 * extract(weekday from date '31.12.2009') day to date '31.12.2009') from rdb$database)) from rdb$database